# Windows keyboard macro playback software?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, macros, playback, event-log

Many years ago, I had a product called Quickeys for the Macintosh that allowed me to record keyboard and mouse events and create a macro that could be assigned to a keyboard accelerator.

This was a really useful tool, but I haven't seen anything like it ever on Microsoft Windows OS platform.

Does such a product exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend AutoHotKey
http://www.autohotkey.com/

"Automate almost anything by sending keystrokes and mouse clicks. You can write a mouse or keyboard macro by hand or use the macro recorder."

I've used this and related tool AutoITv3 -- both great tools -- but I have not yet recorded a macro based on keystrokes.  YMMV.