# How to make alt-backspace delete words in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keymap

I am attempting to make the text editing experience in a Windows workstation I use alongside my OS X systems line up with the keybindings that Cocoa offers.

To start, how would one change mappings so that alt-backspace (in this case it's the option-back-delete key on an older MacBook Pro) deletes entire words?

I would also like to map many other keys differently, such as control-a/e to go to beginning/end of line and a number of other alterations to match it up, but I'd like to start off at the very least with the above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remap the keys on my keyboard?](http://superuser.com/questions/448991/how-do-i-remap-the-keys-on-my-keyboard), [How can I remap a keyboard key?](http://superuser.com/questions/36920/how-can-i-remap-a-keyboard-key), [Windows keyboard macro playback software?](http://superuser.com/questions/138774/windows-keyboard-macro-playback-software)

Comment: Those keystrokes you're mentioning are handled by each application itself, not by the OS. I doubt this is possible. How would this tool know how many characters are in the word? Every application's model under the hood is different.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 This goes beyond simply remapping keys.

Comment: @Steve OP wants to map a key to another key or combination of keys - all answers point to AutoHotKey (or alike), which is much more than "simple key remapping", but it does that too.

Comment: A newer question has arisen which provides better answers: [How to add the Alt+Backspace macOS typing functionality to Windows](https://superuser.com/q/1303178/358758).

Answer (score 4):

Did you know that you can delete words by the combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>?

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> is generally mapped to the "Undo" command.

If you still want to change the behavior, you can use the [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) program.

Answer (score 0):

To faster delete whole words, you can first select them by placing the cursor at the end and pressing <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>. Then proceed by pressing <kbd>Backspace</kbd> or <kbd>Delete</kbd>.

To map the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> behavior to do this, check the links given as "possible duplicates" to your question.